Reset counter for the category "Exercise" in Lyx
¡Hi! I'm trying to do a kind of solution manual for a book and I'm recently learning a little bit of Latex with the help of Lyx. For my document, I'm using the class Book (Standard Class). Well, the problem is that I'm using the category Exercise for enumerate the exercises, but I want that every section the counter goes to zero. I have tried some codes on the internet, but they did not work. This is how the category is defined as far as I can understand.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{xca}[thm]{\protect\exercisename}

This also caught my attention
\usepackage{babel}
\providecommand{\exercisename}{Exercise}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

Every time I insert the category class, is between
\begin{xca}
\end{xca}

If you could help me, I would be very grateful, and apologies for any misspelled words. My first language is not English.
P.D
This is all my code
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.4.2.1 created this file.  For more info, see https://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[letterpaper,english]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{xca}[thm]{\protect\exercisename}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,decorations.markings,calc,positioning,through}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\leftmark}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\providecommand{\exercisename}{Exercise}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\hyphenpenalty=1000
\title{Solution Manual}
\author{Carlos Julio Islas Bustamante Ledesma}
\date{October 21, 2024}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Angles, Parallel Lines, Paralellograms}

\section{Proposition \textmd{\textit{CONSTRUCTING AN EQUILATERAL TRIANGLE.}}\textit{
}\textcolor{red}{(p.p. 33)}}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{{[}1.1{]}}
\end{figure}

\begin{xca}
If the segments $\overline{AF}$and $\overline{BF}$ are constructed,
prove that the figure $\boxdot ACBF$ is a rhombus.
\end{xca}

\begin{proof}
Because $A$ is the center of the circle $\Circle A$, $\overline{AF}=\overline{AB}$
{[}Def. 1.33{]}. Because $B$ is the center of the circle $\Circle B$,
$\overline{BF}=\overline{AB}$ {[}Def. 1.33{]}. Since $\overline{AF}=\overline{BF}=\overline{AB}=\overline{AC}=\overline{BC}$,
it follows that $\boxdot ACBF$ is a rhombus. 

\medskip{}
\end{proof}
\begin{xca}
If $\overline{CF}$ is constructed and $\overline{AB}$ is extended
to the circumferences of the circles (at points $D$ and $E$), prove
that the triangles $\triangle CDF$ and $\triangle CEF$ are equilateral.
\end{xca}

\begin{proof}
Consider $\triangle CAD$, $\triangle DAF$ and $\triangle FAC$.
Because $A$ is the center of the circle $\Circle A$, $\overline{AC}=\overline{AD}=\overline{AF}$.
Next, consider $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ABF$. By {[}1.32{]}
and {[}1.32. Cor 6{]}, $\angle CAD=\angle DAF=\angle FAC$. Since
$\overline{AC}=\overline{AD}=\overline{AF}$ and $\angle CAD=\angle DAF=\angle FAC$,
it follows that $\triangle CAD\cong\triangle DAF\cong\triangle FAC$
and $\overline{CD}=\overline{DF}=\overline{FC}$. So $\triangle CDF$.
analogously it can be shown for $\triangle CEF$. 

\medskip{}
\end{proof}
\begin{xca}
3. If $\overline{CA}$ and $\overline{CB}$ are extended to intersect
the circumferences at points $G$ and $H$, prove that the points
$G$, $F$, $H$ are collinear and that the triangle $\bigtriangleup GCH$
is equilateral.
\end{xca}

\begin{proof}
By {[}1.1, \#1{]}, $\triangle ABF$ is equilateral. By {[}1.32. Cor
6{]}, $\angle CAB=\angle BAF=\frac{2}{3}R=\angle CBA=\angle ABF$.
Since $\angle CAG=2R=\angle CBH$, it follows that $\angle GAF=\frac{2}{3}R=\angle FBH$.
Consider $\bigtriangleup GAF$ and $\bigtriangleup FBH$. Because
$A$ is the center of the circle $\Circle A$, $\overline{AG}=\overline{AF}$
{[}Def. 1.33{]}. Because $B$ is the center of the circle $\Circle B$,
$\overline{BF}=\overline{BH}$ {[}Def. 1.33{]} . Since $\overline{AG}=\overline{AF}$
and $\overline{BF}=\overline{BH}$, it follows that $\bigtriangleup GAF$
and $\bigtriangleup FBH$ are isosceles. Since $\angle GAF=\frac{2}{3}R=\angle FBH$,
it follows that $\angle AGF=\angle AFG=\frac{2}{3}R=\angle BFH=\angle BHF$.
By {[}1.5, Cor 1{]}, $\bigtriangleup GAF$ and $\bigtriangleup FBH$
are equilateral. Since $\angle AFG+\angle AFB=\angle BFH=2R$, it
follows that $G$, $F$ and $H$ are collinear. Consider $\bigtriangleup GCH$.
Since $\overline{CG}=\overline{GH}=\overline{HC}=2\overline{AB}$,
it follows that $\bigtriangleup GCH$ is equilateral.

\medskip{}
\end{proof}
\begin{xca}
Construct $\overline{CF}$ and prove that $\overline{CF}^{2}=3\cdot\overline{AB}^{2}$.
\end{xca}

\begin{proof}
Consider $\bigtriangleup CGF$ and $\bigtriangleup CFH$. Since $\overline{CG}=\overline{CH}$,
$\overline{GF}=\overline{FH}$ and $\bigtriangleup CFH=\angle CHF$,
it follows that $\bigtriangleup CGF\cong\bigtriangleup CFH$. Therefore,
$\angle CFG=1R=\angle CFH$ and $\bigtriangleup CGF\cong\bigtriangleup CFH$
are right triangles. By {[}1.47{]}, $\overline{CF}^{2}=\overline{CH}^{2}-\overline{FH}^{2}$.
But, $\overline{CF}=2\overline{\cdot AB}$ and $\overline{FH}=\overline{AB}$.
So,
\begin{align*}
\overline{CF}^{2} & =\overline{CH}^{2}-\overline{FH}^{2}\\
 & =\left(2\cdot\overline{AB}\right)^{2}-\overline{AB}^{2}\\
 & =4\cdot\overline{AB}^{2}-\overline{AB}^{2}\\
 & =3\cdot\overline{AB}.
\end{align*}
\medskip{}
\end{proof}
\begin{xca}
Construct a circle in the space $ACB$ bounded by the segment $\overline{AB}$
and the partial circumferences of the two circles.
\end{xca}

\begin{proof}
Consider the midpoints $I$, $J$ and $K$ of $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{BC}$
and $\overline{CA}$ respectively. Construct $\bigtriangleup IJK$.
Next, construct the bisectors $\overline{LI}$, $\overline{MJ}$ and
$\overline{NK}$ of $\bigtriangleup IJK$, with the vertices $I$,
$J$ and $K$ respectively. Consider the circumcenter $O$ of $\bigtriangleup IJK$.
By {[}1.11, \#5{]}, $\overline{IO}=\overline{JO}=\overline{KO}$.
Construct $\Circle O$ with radius $\overline{IO}=\overline{JO}=\overline{KO}$.
Consider $\bigtriangleup AOB$, $\bigtriangleup BOC$ \#\#\#\#\#\#\#

\medskip{}
\end{proof}

\section{Proposition \textmd{\textit{CONSTRUCTING A LINE SEGMENT EQUAL IN
LENGTH TO AN ARBITRARY LINE SEGMENT.}}\textit{ }\textcolor{red}{(p.p.
33)}}

\section{Proposition \textmd{\textit{SUBDIVIDING A LINE SEGMENT.}}\textit{
}\textcolor{red}{(p.p. 33)}}

\section{Proposition \textmd{\textit{THE ``SIDE-ANGLE-SIDE'' THEOREM FOR
THE CONGRUENCE OF TRIANGLES.}}\textit{ }\textcolor{red}{(p.p. 33)}}
\begin{xca}
\end{xca}

\begin{proof}
Construct the triangle $\triangle ABC$ and construct the equilateral
triangles $\triangle ABD$, $\triangle BCE$ and $\triangle CAF$.
Construct the segments $AE$, $BF$ and $CD$. Consider $\triangle BCD$
and $\triangle ABE$. Since $AB=DB$, $BC=BE$ and $\angle DBC=\angle DBA+\angle ABC=\angle ABC+\angle CBE=\angle ABE$,
by {[}1.4{]}, $\triangle BCD\cong\triangle ABE$. Therefore, $AE=CD$.
Next, consider 
\end{proof}

\end{document}


I'm already found it. There is an option in the "Edit" menu that says "Manage Counter Values". In "Counter" you select "Theorem" and in "Action" you select "Reset Counter to 0". Thats all.
